# Error while running example

Tags: opencv, debian

I installed opencv 2.3.1 and when I execute samples by running the command `./delaunay` on the terminal, I got errors as follows:

```
This program builds the traingulation interactively, you may stop this process by
hitting any key.

OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script) in cvNamedWindow, file /home/pi/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 275 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'

  what():  /home/pi/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:275: error: (-2) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function cvNamedWindow

Aborted
```

What is the solution?

Comment: I am not familiar with openvc, but I wonder what `./delauney` is?

Comment: @Tshepang, delaunay triangulation is a way of making a triangulated mesh from points in the plane

Comment: @dhanash, no idea, how you 'installed' opencv on your box, if that installed 'binaries', they're obviously faulty. if it installed 'code', and you were running cmake or such to build the opencv binaries, believe the error message, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config before trying again

Comment: btw, 2.3.1 is like 2 years old(yuccc, no face recognition, no stitching, gpu/ocl support, superscale, whatever), current version is 2.4.6. you're probably better off, building it from [source](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/2.4)